# How can I make a dataframe whose values are a list in r?

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I am trying to take my tibble that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 52,300 × 3
     `-1` semester major
    <int> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 353323 0            0
 2 353323 1            0
 3 353323 2            0
 4 353324 0            1
 5 353324 1            1
 6 353324 2            1
 7 353324 3            0
 8 353325 0            0
 9 353325 1            1
10 353325 2            1
```

I want to make a dataframe that creates a single row for each value in `-1`, whose 'semester' value is a list of all the values for which 'major' is 1. e.g.

```
   `-1` semester major
    <int> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 353323 NA            1
 2 353324 0,1,2         1
 3 353325 1,2           1
```

Any clues on how I do that?

I am basically unsure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your output to be a list then:

```r
dat  |>
    summarise(semester = list(semester[major==1]), .by = `-1`)

#       -1 semester
# 1 353323         
# 2 353324    0,1,2
# 3 353325      1,2
```

Alternatively if you want a character vector:

```r
dat  |>
    summarise(semester = paste(semester[major==1], collapse = ","), .by = `-1`)
```